# Что не так с регуляркой?

Tags: javascript, php, регулярные-выражения

Регулярка в php, которая должна охватывать русские буквы, не находит букву "Ф":

```
echo preg_match("/^[а-яА-ЯЁё]+$/", "ф"); // возвращает 0
```

При этом в JS все работает нормально:

```
console.log(/^[а-яА-ЯЁё]+$/.test('ф')) // возвращает true
```